# SlickGrid Dissapearing Frozen Column data on sorting with Horizontal Scroll at the end

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am  facing issue with slick grid. i have total 31 columns where 2  colums are frozen. when i move horizontal scroller to the right and try to sort grid by clicking on any header columns then frozen columns data are vanished. when i move the scroller to the left and again click on same header column then it works fine. this issue got fixed by making some changes in slick.grid.new.js  as given below i have added 'd' appendCellHtml in the last else if.

```
if (columnPosRight[Math.min(ii - 1, i + colspan - 1)] > range.leftPx) {
          if (columnPosLeft[i] > range.rightPx) {
            break;
          }

          if (( options.frozenColumn > -1 ) && ( i > options.frozenColumn )) {
            appendCellHtml(stringArrayR, row, i, colspan, d);
          } else {
            appendCellHtml(stringArrayL, row, i, colspan, d);
          }
        } else if (( options.frozenColumn > -1 ) && ( i <= options.frozenColumn )) {
          appendCellHtml(stringArrayL, row, i, colspan,d);
        }
```

But i think this might be risk for other slik grids as it is common code. Please suggest what alternative i can use here.

Comment: You'll need to let us know what SlickGrid repo you are using. Frozen columns is not a feature in the standard repo.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue; appending 'd' as last parameter for the appendCellHtml, works for me without any issue.
I am using [JYnch7 fork](https://github.com/JLynch7/SlickGrid).